# Javascript InnerHTML text not changing

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason the `ID= employer` won't change to `employerCont` (which is 34.07.  It just continues to say `test1`.  Does anyone know why?

```
<div id="main" style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:500px; height:500px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="content" style="background-color:gray; width:500px; height:500px;">
<p id="employer">test1</p>
<p id="employee">test2</p>
</div>

<script src="C:\Documents and Settings\zx08067\Desktop\HSA_RaphaelGraph\raphael.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Documents and Settings\zx08067\Desktop\HSA_RaphaelGraph\g.raphael.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

function calculatePercentages (var EE, var ER) {
    var sum = EE + ER;
    var EE_perc = EE / sum;
    var ER_perc = ER / sum;

}

//employee and employer contributions
var employeeCont = 251.34;
var employerCont = 34.07;

document.getElementById("employer").innerHTML = employerCont;

calculatePercentages(employeeCont, employerCont);

var tee=[0,0,500,500, 
{type:"path", path:"M58.5,50, C58.5,43 51.5,43 51.5,50, C51.5,57 58.5,57 58.5,50", fill:"green", "stroke-width":"0"},
{type:"path", path:"M52,52 L58,52 L58,70 L55,78 L52,70 L52,52", fill:"green", "stroke-width":"0"}, 
{type:"path", path:"M57,49, C57,46 53,46 53,49 C53,52.5 57,52.5 57,50", fill:"white", "stroke-width":"0"}
];

document.getElementById("main") = Raphael(tee);

</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: No.  What do you see in the browser's Javascript console? It will show you your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Cameron's answer, try calling once the document has finished loading.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("employer").innerHTML = employerCont;
}
```

No jQuery required.

Comment: NICE, I will accept your answer when it lets me.  Thanks Nicholas :)

Comment: I do a lot of work where I'm not allowed to make calls to external sites so consequently I am required to use a lot of raw JavaScript. People shy away from it but it's really not that bad.

Comment: @NickChapman You can download and import Jquery to your HTML as well. There is no need to point it to an online server.

Comment: @Jerry Oh I know, it's just that I'm on a lot of servers so downloading it and installing it every time is a hassle. For simple scripts its quicker to just bust it out with the base.

Comment: @akinuri That was one of the problems and a good catch on your part, but the contents of a tag were also not changing. Whether or not it was related to the function arguments issue, who knows? But it looks like this solution worked.

Comment: Once you remove the `var` from the arguments it works. That's why I added a demo. Besides he didn't call it in the head and the p element is before the script, so there's no need for `onload`. `var`'s in the arguments was causing the problem. Am  I wrong?

Comment: Well it sets up that function but doesn't call it yet. I don't know if the incorrect function would throw off the entire script block but the innerHTML that was supposed to be modified happens before the broken function was called. Therefore it would make me think that something else is the root of the problem, perhaps loading times. The thing with loading times is that it might seem to work in one browser or online editor but not work in another. I upvoted your solution because it fixes a problem we would have had to deal with later, but I dont know fi it fixes the problem we started with.

Comment: Well, it changes the `p#employer`'s value to `34.07`. Which I think that was the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Mistype.

```
function calculatePercentages (var EE, var ER)
```

Remove vars.

```
function calculatePercentages (EE, ER)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qBTA9/)

Answer (score 0):

Stripping away the non critical code to solve your specific question seemed to fix the issue. [working code on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/erIJaxI/1/edit)